# I want to see the post created in the same month of Carbon::now

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

```
public function showallcategoryfood(){
$carbon = Carbon::now(); 
$foods=Food::all();
DB::table('food')->whereMonth('created_at','=',$carbon);
return view('test.logout')->with('foods',$foods);
}
```

It keeps showing all the records, its not taking it by the month of June!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods)?

> The whereMonth method may be used to compare a column's value against a specific month of a year:

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '12')
                ->get();
```

So in your case it will be:

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)
                ->get();
```

Comment: This solution will suits most of the cases, but just keep in mind it will consider month start and end with the server (Laravel app) timezone.

Answer (score 1):

The `all()` method returns the underlying array represented by the collection.

Try this :

```
public function showallcategoryfood(){
   $carbon = Carbon::now()->format('m');
   $foods=Food::whereMonth('created_at', '=', $carbon)->get();
   return view('test.logout')->with('foods', $foods);   
}
```